# VB6 - After compiled getting compatibility issue on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: vb6

I'm using

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98
vb6.exe /make Project1 /out %1
```

To basically compile my application, and I'm getting a compatibility issue (Saying doesn't work on my type of windows). When compiling with the VB6 IDE (Make .exe) that works perfectly on my machine but this isn't, does anybody know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using the command prompt instead of the IDE to compile your application?

Comment: Basically using it for a web compiler, has to be used. Do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you post the exact error? Does the error occur immediately on trying to start your application? What solutions have you already tried, if any?

Comment: I'm not sure what a "web compiler" is, but if this means sharing one copy among multiple users this would violate the license terms.  Quote: "You may install copies of the SOFTWARE PRODUCT on an unlimited number of computers provided that you are the only individual using the SOFTWARE PRODUCT. If you are an entity, Microsoft grants you the right to designate one individual within your organization to have the sole right to use the SOFTWARE PRODUCT in the manner provided above."

Comment: Oh, nothing like that Bob77, hard to explain and it's not even relevant. @Holistic Developer The error is "This version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 32-bit or a x64 64-bit version of the program, the contact the software publisher".

Comment: @SRC that seems to imply that the resulting executable is 16-bit and you're trying to run it on a 64-bit system -- which is strange because to my knowledge VB4 was the last version to support 16-bit apps. You are compiling and running this on the same machine?

Also, it is a good idea to edit your question to include the information that people are asking for in the comments -- it will make it easier for others to see all the relevant information together.

Comment: Is it a "Standard EXE" project?

Comment: Yes, It's a standard EXE project

Comment: Still need help, please help me.

Comment: @SRC How is piracy not relevant?  We do not help pirates here.  Perhaps you can describe a possible legitimate use case for this?