# VB6 compiling via console (vb.exe) compatibility issue on 64bit (works on 32bit?)

Tags: vb6

I'm using

```
    cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98
vb6.exe /make Project1 /out %1
```

To basically compile my application, and I'm getting a compatibility issue (**Saying doesn't work on my type of windows**).

When compiling with the VB6 IDE (Make .exe) that works perfectly on my machine but this isn't, does anybody know how to fix this? Thanks

Error I receive when trying to open executable: "This version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 32-bit or a x64 64-bit version of the program, the contact the software publisher".

& It's a **standard EXE application also**.

I've tried running it as a administrator, trouble shooting / changing the compatibility to **windows XP service pack 2 & 3**, still didn't work.

Work prefer a good fix to this, like if there's anything I can do via console as a option or something or some option or anything.

Cheers! Please help ASAP

Comment: Note that VB6 development on 64bit Windows is not supported. Running VB6 application is but not development. See: [Support Statement for Visual Basic 6.0 on Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, and Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/ms788708.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Brain, but it still works if I build it via the IDE but not building it via console. Still need help, willing to pay a lot.

Comment: Some do such work in Windows XP Mode which is included with Windows 7 Professional and higher Editions. This lets you do the work in a Windows XP Pro 32bit environment in a virtual machine.

Comment: I understand but, I need this to work on all window machines pretty much & has to be compiled via a console application.

Comment: No-repro, compiles just fine on Windows 7 x64. The `/out` parameter specifies the log file, not the exe file, aren't you trying to run that log file by any chance? The exe name is automatically taken from the project properties.

Comment: @GSerg now when compiling with: vb6.exe /make Project1 I'm getting "No make available in the Working Model Edition"?

Comment: Then you apparently have VB6 Working Model Edition that does not support `/make`, as opposed to full VB6 version that does.

Comment: Oh right okay, I'll go install the actual version

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB6 - After compiled getting compatibility issue on Windows 7 64bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598740/vb6-after-compiled-getting-compatibility-issue-on-windows-7-64bit)

Comment: @GSerg Interesting, I have never heard of the Working Model Edition before!

Comment: @HolisticDeveloper Me either, but google seems to know people who tried to /make executables with it and failed, so I thought it existed after all.

Comment: @GSerg So whenever I try to actually /make a executable, I'm getting an apparent code error with one of my files in my resources, even though I can run it perfectly & build it perfectly with the IDE any ideas how to skip these errors?

Comment: Like the error I'm getting is apparently in my resource file file.cl which is in a totally different native language.

Comment: @SRC if you're getting a different error now, you should ask a new question. I think we've answered the original problem (see answer I just posted below).

Answer (score 1):

From the discussion in the comments, I believe the answer here is as follows (as identified by GSerg):

The problem is your use of the `/make` switch on the command line. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231236%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) says this about `/out`:

> Outputs errors to a file when used with the /make or /makedll switch.

So, if you used `vb6.exe /make Project1 /out Project1.exe`, then Project1.exe would actually be a text file containing the error output from the compiler and thus would not be an actual executable, even though it had an .exe extension.

You actually don't specify the output binary when you use `/make`. The help output from running `VB6.exe /?` is a little more explicit:

> Tells Visual Basic to compile projectname and make an executable file
>   from it, using the existing settings stored in the project file.

VB remembers the last filename and directory you used for compiling your project in the IDE, and it stores that in the .vbp file:

```
ExeName32="Project1.exe"
Path32="..\output"
```

Comment: Hi, I can't actually seem to get this working correctly: cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98
vb6.exe /make C:/projectpath/Project1 /out ohnoes.txt
pause

Comment: It basically won't find the path for it, and I can't find another command such as /makedir in the documentation, any ideas?

Comment: If you want to run vb6.exe at the command line, you will find it easier if you put `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98` in your path. Then, see if you can just run the command at a command prompt (not in a batch file). From the directory where your project is located, run `vb6 /make Project1.vbp`.

Comment: I'm now getting "Unexpected error occurred in code generator link".

Comment: I see you have a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687662/getting-a-error-when-compiling-not-with-the-ide) so I'll answer there.

Answer (score 0):

I use a batch file to handle this issue.  It sets the path to include both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the Program Files directories.  Then just reference 'vb6.exe' and the correct one will be pulled from your path.

```
set PATH=c:"\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\bin"
set PATH=%PATH%;c:"\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98"
set PATH=%PATH%;c:"\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\bin"
set PATH=%PATH%;c:"\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98"
vb6 /m foobar.vpb
```