# What are the possible causes of "Unexpected error occurred in code generator or linker" when using VB6?

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, vb6

I am trying to compile a Visual Basic 6 project at the command line using the following command:

```
vb6.exe /make Project.vbp
```

I'm getting an error that states

> "Unexpected error occurred in code generator or linker

What are the possible causes of this error?

if you want to read my past issue here's the link: [VB6 compiling via console (vb.exe) compatibility issue on 64bit (works on 32bit?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665182/vb6-compiling-via-console-vb-exe-compatibility-issue-on-64bit-works-on-32bit/20670017?noredirect=1#comment30954791_20670017)

Really would appreciate all help, would even donate/pay for actual remote assistance not sure if that's allowed on stackoverflow though.

Comment: Is that the only error?

Comment: yes that's the only error ;)

Answer (score 3):

1. This can happen if your .exp or .lib files are read only. From [Q201565: PRB: Visual Basic Read-only .exp/.lib Files Cause Compile Error](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/201/Q201565/):

   ```
   CAUSE
   =====

   The <project name>.exp and/or <project name>.lib files in the
   project directory are read-only.

   RESOLUTION
   ==========

   Change the read-only attribute to read/write.
   ```
2. This can happen if you are compiling a project upgraded from VB5. From [Q193089: PRB: Unexpected Error Occurs in Code Generator or Linker](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/193/Q193089/):

   ```
   CAUSE
   =====

   This is caused by the existence of a project.pdb (symbol) file in the directory
   into which you are compiling the project.

   RESOLUTION
   ==========

   There are two possible resolutions to this issue:

   - Delete the existing .pdb file.

     -or-

   - Compile the project (exe or dll) into a different directory.
   ```

Comment: Nope, none of the resource files / project files are ready only, and it's a pure VB 6.0 project.

Comment: @SRC those were the first reasons I could find, but googling the error turned up a lot of results; you might have to sift through them for ideas.

Comment: Still need help if anybody can.

Answer (score 0):

The `/outdir` followed by an output directory must be specified.

Try something like:

```
vb6.exe /make Project.vbp /outdir c:\temp\VB6Out
```